# why styles don't apply on dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, i18next

i need to render some styled jsx tags in my component by using useTranslation hook and dangerouslySetInnerHTML, those tags are stored in a json file , i found that dangerouslySetInnerHTML work's fine but don't apply tailwind styles for each tag,

json file:

```
{
   "about-text":"<div className='text-blue px-5'><p>Text ...</p</div>",
}
```

inside componenets:

```
<div className="p-10">
<div
   dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: t('about-text'),
    }}
   />
</div>
```

Comment: Will the JSON file you've shown here be matched by the paths that you have provided to `content` in Tailwind's configuration? If not, Tailwind won't compile those classes (assuming they're not used anywhere else).

Comment: Could it be because `about-text` contains **broken** html?

Answer (score 8):

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` expects to be passed a string of HTML, not a string of JSX.

The `class` attribute is used directly. You can't adjust the `className` property instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a  tag that worked for me, using Tailwind:

`<a class="hover:text-blue-600" href="some youtube link" target="_blank">https://.com</a>`

Just use "class" instead of "className" for the dangerouslySetInnerHTML CSS class.